# How to retrieve the first n characters of a variable in Bash?

Tags: bash

How to retrieve the first 10 characters of a variable with Bash?

```
FOO="qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm"
```

I need to get `qwertzuiop`.

Comment: That isn't correct assignment syntax. `foo=${foo:0:10}` ... `foo=${foo%%"${foo##??????????}"}`

Answer (score 179):

If the variable is: `FOO="qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm"`

then

```
 echo ${FOO:0:10}
```

will give the first 10 characters.

Answer (score 93):

Use the `head` command.

```
echo $FOO | head -c 10
=> qwertzuiop
```

Comment: I think this answer make the most sense, and works at the end of a long line used to generate the string `FOO`.

Comment: This is _much_ slower and resource-intensive than `${FOO:0:10}`.