# Command for printing part of a String?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal, command

I have a file name `test`,
it contains a String `James Bond 007`,
and i want to print only `James Bond`.
I tried the following commands:

```
$ strings -n 2 test
$ sed -n '/James/,/Bond/p' test
$ awk '{print substr($1,10)}' test
```

Comment: What is the general criteria for what you want to print? The first two words, the first 10 characters?

Comment: either of them will do but i would like to know both them :)

Comment: echo James Bond 007 | awk '{print $1" "$2}' ; 
echo James Bond 007 | cut -d " " -f1,2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/428109/608639), [How to retrieve the first n characters of a variable in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14992658/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2):

To print the first two words, you can use `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1, $2}' test
```

To print the first ten characters, you can put the file contents in a variable, then use the `bash` substring operation:

```
contents=$(cat test)
echo "${contents:0:10}"
```

Or in `awk`:

```
awk '{print substr($0, 1, 10)}' test
```

Notice that `$0` means the whole line, and you have to give both a starting index and length to `substr()`. Indexes in `awk` start at `1` rather than `0`.

In `sed`, `/James/,/Bond/` is a line range expression; it processes all the lines starting from a line containing `James` until a line containing `Bond`. It doesn't process just part of the lines.